# Mask out effect in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking

I have some glare effects on my image that looks fine on some places but ugly on others, in fact I don't even want it to appear on certain parts of the image. 
Is there a way to just mask out this effect using a black-white texture map for example, so that the image's lower parts get glare while the upper parts don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should do the trick. Set the glare node's **Mix**
 value to **1**. This will cause it to only output the glare, not the mixed image. Then, simply use an **Add** node to mix the glare onto the original image, using your black and white Mask imagein the **Add** node's **Fac** to Mask out where you want no glare. In the example below, black would be no glare and white would be full glare.

[image]